# TFS 2010 Branching Error on Label TF10169

Tags: .net, tfs, branch

I can't create a branch in TFS; when I try to branch the code in $/MainCode to $/BranchCode, using a label as the source, I get this error:

TF10169: Unsupported pending change attempted on team project folder $/BranchCode.  Use the Project Creation Wizard in Team Explorer to create a project or the Team Project deletion tool to delete one.

Why would I need to create or delete a project?  Both $/MainCode and $/BranchCode exist.......  I don't get this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I might be completely wrong here, but isn't it the case that the things *immediately* below `$/` are Team Projects, rather than branches? So you would have

```
$
    SuperFoo
        Main
        vNext
    AmazingBar
        Main
        vNext
        vNextNext
```

and you would branch (say) `$/SuperFoo/Main` to `$/SuperFoo/MyNewBranch` ?

I can't right now find decent docs on Team Projects, and my experience is only with TFS 2005, but that's how I've always understood the hierarchy.

Comment: The other option is to create a new team project and branch into that project once it is created.

Comment: @Robaticus is that option a true branch, or is this like a copy operation?